# String to global variable?

Tags: python, string, global-variables, instantiation

I need to instantiate some keys of a Dict as a standalone global variables.

(Before you object let me mention that this is purely for testing purposes and i know it pollutes the global scope. It is not intended as programing technique.)

OK. Now that out of the way. If I use simple function like the one below it works.

```
def items_as_vars(obj, lst) :
    for i in lst :
        globals()[i] = obj.g(i)
        print i, obj.g(i)
```

> items_as_vars(obj, ['circle','square'])
>
> print circle

but the moment I move this to become class method in a separate file it stops working i.e.

```
class blah:
    @staticmethod
    def items_as_vars(obj, lst) :
       for i in lst :
            globals()[i] = obj.g(i)
            print i, obj.g(i)
```

> blah.items_as_vars(obj, ['circle','square'])
>
> print circle

```
NameError: name 'circle' is not defined
```

any idea why ?
By "stop working", I mean the global variables are no longer instantiated.

---

More info: It seems to work when the class is in the same file, but not when the class is imported !

---

modified to static method, it is the same behaviour.

Comment: stops working? how? [mcve] please. Those 2 are equivalent.

Comment: Works fine for me...you're going to need to provide a more complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `__builtin__` to create cross-module variables. Like this:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def g(self, x):
        return x
    def items_as_vars(self, lst) :
        for i in lst :
            import __builtin__
            setattr(__builtin__, str(i), self.g(i))
            print i, self.g(i)

In [9]: import test

In [10]: test.SomeClass().items_as_vars(['x', 'yz'])
x x
yz yz

In [11]: yz
Out[11]: 'yz'
```

Comment: that worked out, thanks